# Rdlc Report - Parameter

Tags: report, rdlc, param

I write a windows form application in c#.

In this application I have report with parameter. I need to pass a parameter to a report in int64 format.

In rdlc I have only Integer value for report parameter. How I can solve it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the values to string using the str() function on main report and change report parameter in subreport to string

It worked for me. I hope this helps

Comment: I create a new report with string parameter. Seem strange that microsoft not permit use of int64 parameter. Thanks